# How can forms be made to submit with AJAX / jQuery / JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a PHP website, which has a lot of forms that goes to certain pages on submit. So they look like this:

```
<form method='post' action='form_target.php'>
    <input type='text' name='fieldname' />
    <button type='submit'/>
</form>
```

I guess the same thing can be done with `$.post('form-target.php');`, without actually leaving the page. But I'm trying to prevent writing JavaScript code for a lot of different forms.

So is there a simple way to detect forms on the page, and convert them to AJAX calls? Maybe by bind `onsubmit()` , or `onclick();` events to a `$.post();` call?

Any help to implement this will also be appreciated.

Comment: `$('form').onsubmit(...)` should be easy enough.

Comment: @MarcB you mean .submit() or .on('submit'

Comment: Yes, you're example of using onsubmit would be a clean approach. (using the correct jQuery method for binding to the submit event of course)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX submit form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attach the `.submit` event to all forms to catch the submission, then use `.preventDefault()` on the event object to prevent actual page submission (stop it from changing page). Then serialize the form's data (make a name-value paired string), get the url from the action attribute of the form element and then call jquery's ajax function

using `$("form")` with nothing else as part of the selector will attach this to all forms on the page

HTML

```
<form method='post' action='form_target.php'>
    <input type='text' name='fieldname' />
    <button type='submit'/>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    var url = $(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax({
       url:url,
       type:"POST",
       data:data,
       success:function(){
          //do something when post succedes 
       },
       error:function() {
          // do something when it fails
       }
    });
});
```

<kbd>**[JQuery .ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax)**</kbd>

<kbd>**[JQuery .serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize)**</kbd>

<kbd>**[JQuery .submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit)**</kbd>

To further extend this you could make it so each form executes a specific success method, this would help in the case that you need something specific to happen for a specific form submission.

First give each form a data-* attribute that we can later use in the submit event to trigger a specific function for that form.

```
<form method='post' action='form_target.php' 
                    data-onerror="nameSubmitError" 
                    data-onsuccess="nameSubmitSuccess">
```

Then create the two functions that we named in the data-* attributes

```
function nameSubmitError() {
  //Do some code that will handle the error
}

function nameSubmitSuccess() {
  //Do some code that will handle the success
}
```

And in the .submit event

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    var url = $(this).attr("action");
    var errorCallback = $(this).data("onerror");
    var successCallback = $(this).data("onsuccess");
    $.ajax({
       url:url,
       type:"POST",
       success:function(){
          //Check that we have a defined function before trying to execute it
          if( typeof(window[successCallback]) == "function" ) {
             //We do have a defined function so execute it
             window[successCallback]();
          }
       },
       error:function() {
          //Check that we have a defined function before trying to execute it
          if( typeof(window[errorCallback]) == "function" ) {
             //We do have a defined function so execute it
             window[errorCallback]();
          }
       }
    });
});
```

Of course putting all the callback functions in the global space would pollute it so you could setup all the functions into a single object and use the objects name instead of `window`

```
var formCallbacks = {
    nameSubmitError:function() {
      //Do some code that will handle the error
    },
    nameSubmitSuccess: function() {
      //Do some code that will handle the success
    }
};
```

And in the .submit event change `window` to `formCallbacks`

```
//window[errorCallback]();
//Becomes 
formCallbacks[errorCallback]();
```

Comment: wow, how did you style those links at the end?

Comment: `<kbd></kbd>` around the links

Comment: I tried your solution, (after loading jquery) console does not show any errors but forms still submit by going to the page. success and error functions are not called either. It's like I haven't added the script at all. Should I write this script after the forms ? **Edit** : I wrapped your code in `$document.ready(function(){});` now it works but gives an error. I will try to fix it :) Thanks for your help! And thanks to all the other answers.

Comment: Oh, I have added `data:data,` after `type:"POST",`, now it completely works :) Thank you again !

Comment: Yea forgot to add the data option sorry, edited to correct, and also added how you can extend this so you can execute specific callbacks for each form.

Comment: I find all those form attributes unnecessary. It makes the unobtrusive script intrusive, one of the things I dislike about DOJO. Just have the callbacks defined in code and you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can try http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ , this is very simple to use..

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
    <script> 
        // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
            $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
                alert("Thank you for your submit!"); 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm" method='post' action='form_target.php'>
       <input type='text' name='fieldname' />
       <button type='submit'/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @CengizFrostclaw And you can of course replace `#myForm` with `form` to target all forms.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    // Your AJAX call
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
  $.post(
    $(this).prop('action'), // Your url action
    $(this).serialize(),    // Your data
    success: function() {   // Your callback function
      alert('Submitted');
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: dont forget to `preventDefault` or `return false` to prevent the page from changing

Comment: @PatrickEvans yes I was gonna ask that. And what is prop? Can I use `attr()` instead of it ? and moreover, will it convert "form_target" to "http://mysite.com/form_target" ?

Comment: and this gives the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :